# accordion isn't is working but showing and hiding the active class

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angular

Uncaught TypeError: this.accordioncontent is undefined
accordionopenclose http://localhost:5500/assets/js/app.js:36

i am a super basic person pls help me with this is the structure of my code i want when the button is clicked by the user the accordion will be showing and hiding the content according to the click event and by default the accordion content is set to display none and i think there is issue in between the dom traversal method

```
html code
 <div class="accordioncontainer">
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordioncontainerinner">
        <div class="accordionopenclose">open close accordion</div>
        <div class="accordioncontent">
          <p class="accordiontext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere sint ex iusto eos dolores, asperiores dignissimos aut odio voluptatem quidem quaerat perspiciatis quasi ullam iure nesciunt odit nostrum non placeat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

css code

.accordioncontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  padding: 20px 150px;
}

.accordioncontainer .accordionopenclose {
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--primarycolor);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  /* font-weight: 600; */
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primarycolor);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* display: inline; */
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.accordioncontainer .accordionopenclose:hover,
.accordioncontainer .accordionopenclose .active {
  background: var(--primarycolor);
  color: var(--backgroundcolor);
}

.accordioncontainerinner .accordioncontent {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.accordioncontent p {
  display: none;
}

javascript code 
 
let accordionopenclose = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionopenclose");
let accordioncontent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordioncontent");
let xyz;

for (let xyz = 0; xyz < accordionopenclose.length; xyz++) {
  accordionopenclose[xyz].addEventListener(
    "click",
    function accordionopenclose() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      accordioncontent = this.accordioncontent[xyz].parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
      if (accordioncontent.style.display === "block") {
        accordioncontent.style.display === "none";
      } else {
        accordioncontent.style.display === "block";
      }
    }
  );
}
```

the accordion will be open and close when the button is clicked